# config sql server connection in hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, database-connection

I want to connect to sql server in hibernate with windows authentication as the login methond. So my config as this but not connect to sql.

I also add sql maven dependency to pom.xml.
I try with comuter name and localhost in url connection but not connect to db.

```
 <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            <prop key="cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
                com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://.;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">windows username
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">windows password
            </prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
        </props>
  </property>
```

this exeption apear in out put

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1105)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
```

Comment: Why are you giving `;` separated values in `hibernate.connection.url` ?

Comment: @Rehman url connection format have semi colon (;)

Comment: Are you getting any exception? if so please post it

Comment: @Rehman I put exceptions.

Comment: @HJZ did you use sqljdbc_auth.dll ?

Comment: Please make sure you are giving a correct username and password

Comment: @ karim mohsen yea i add this dll in tow place. 1) add java path library . 2) tomcat bin dir.

Comment: @ Rehman i use windows authentication as the login methond. so i add windows username as username and windows pass as pass.

Comment: @HJZ try coping sqljdbc_auth.dll(64 or 82) according to your windows in C:\Windows\System32